# Yii2, не выводить пагинатор

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Добрый день! У меня такой вопрос:

Есть view где я вывожку виджет ListView

```
<?= ListView::widget( [
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'itemView' =>    '_etc/item_list',                          
                        ]);
        ?>
```

Появляется виджет и пагинатор снизу, по дизайну мне нужно чтобы пагинатор был в другом месте и поэтому я использую такой код:

```
<?= \yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([
                    'pagination'=>$dataProvider->pagination,
                ]);
```

Естественно появляется ещё один пагинатор. Собственно вопрос: как убрать первый пагинатор? Можно ли с какими-то параметрами выводить ListView, чтобы отсутствовала меню пагинации снизу его?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно через layout

```
<?= ListView::widget( [
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_etc/item_list',
    'layout'=>"{summary}\n{items}",
]);?>
```

Либо через свойство **pager**, и указать свою заглушку или реализацию